# What is the corresponding keyboard keys to Google Glass touchpad actions?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid, google-glass

I used Settings.apk and Launcher2.apk to access to Android setting and paired Glass with my Bluetooth keyboard device. Now I can use arrow keys, escape and return to control my glass. If I only use left and right arrows I can not select to some items in Glass but I can select every thing by swipe forward and back on touchpad. Is there a keycode that can be directly mapped to touchpad action? Or does it needs special HID consumer report?

Answer (score 5):

The `KeyEvent`'s action you can intercept is `ACTION_DOWN`.

The key codes are:

- `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` (tap)
- `KEYCODE_TAB` (horizontal swipes; `isShiftPressed()` returns `true` for backward [left] swipes and `false` for forward [right] swipes)
- `KEYCODE_CAMERA` (camera button)
- `KEYCODE_BACK` (swipe down, acts like back button)

There is no key code equivalent for a swipe up.

Comment: Thanks, I tried tab, shift tab and they works well in apps but not in Glass interface. I tried arror left and right and they don't work in apps. Which is weird.

Comment: I wrote a simple activity that prints onKeyDown events and I got those, try using KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT and KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT or write your own to see what events are fired.

Comment: @ferdy182 I've tried that and am having no luck with DPAD RIGHT/LEFT. They just don't get captured at all. Here's a gist:  https://gist.github.com/tetreault/0036ec122cae50c540e9

Comment: I don't think that works anymore, now you have to use a gesture detector. See the docs https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch